# Property 'env' does not exist on type 'CypressNpmApi'

Tags: typescript, cypress, dotenv

I am getting this typescript error when trying to use cypress.env.json file.

**cypress.env.json**

```
{
  "email": "myemail@somewhere.com",
  "password": "Password123"
}
```

**steps.ts**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import Cypress from 'cypress';

Given(/I login to TMDB/, url => {
  Cypress.env('email'); // <- error here
});
```

> Property 'env' does not exist on type 'CypressNpmApi'

https://github.com/inspiraller/next-cypress-cucumber-boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to - https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/565#event-4746536875

Was resolved by simply removing my import of Cypress. Since this should be automatically avaiable via typescript in tsconfig.json

Updated code

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

// import Cypress from 'cypress'; <- remove this line

Given(/I login to TMDB/, url => {
  Cypress.env('email'); // <- Now correctly works
});
```